# flyway clean drop multiple users/schemas

Tags: flyway

On oracle 12.2 docker container, flyway migrate creates multiple schemas, SchemaA, SchemaB. However, the flyway clean only drops user SchemaA but not SchemaB, and cleans both SchemaA and SchemaB. How do I get clean to drop user SchemaB too?